# Regexp with letters and hexadecimal

Tags: ruby, regex

I need regexp for "`EWD-eb-AEW-97-QOW`" like strings.

The general pattern is: 
3 uppercase letters, hex, 3 uppercase letters, hex, 3 uppercase letters.

I use:

```
/[A-Z]{3}-\h-[A-Z]{3}-\h-[A-Z]{3}/
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone help with it and explain why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use something like:

```
/(?:[A-Z]{3}-[a-f0-9]{2}-){2}[A-Z]{3}/
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/aY5eF6/1

```
(?:[A-Z]{3}-[a-f0-9]{2}-)
```

groups the three-letters, `'-'`, two hexadecimal letters, and `'-'`, and then does it twice, followed by three-letters again.

---

Regarding using Ruby's `\h` Regexp extension:

I'd be careful using special characters like `\h` in a mixed-language environment, or one that is supporting old versions of Ruby. We use YAML to contain patterns shared among various languages, and something like this would open up a very hard to track bug. I'd recommend using `[a-f0-9]` unless you KNOW you'll never run into that problem.

Answer (score 2):

`\h` doesn't match 2 digit hex numbers, use this regex:

```
/[A-Z]{3}-[A-F0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{3}-[A-F0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{3}/i
```

[RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/gLXvpm1KBv)

Comment: \h matches 1 digit hex numbers?.. am i missing something here.. https://regex101.com/r/mZ1aT2/3

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html --> More Shorthand Character Classes --> last line refers to "Ruby 1.9 and later have their own version of \h. It matches a single hexadecimal digit just like [0-9a-fA-F]".. this is wrong?

Comment: @karthikmanchala; Yes you're right and I've upvoted your answer +1 but your reference to regex101 is wrong since that is not Ruby regex

Answer (score 2):

In addition to anubhava's answer.. You can add `{2}` occurrences in your answer for achieving the same.

```
/[A-Z]{3}-\h{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\h{2}-[A-Z]{3}/i
```

See [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/agrxtrF2ZZ)

Comment: No, you can't `\h` doesn't mean hexadecimal values, it means horizontal whitespace. The use of `\h` is a fatal flaw in the pattern that keeps it from matching the target string.

Comment: In Ruby `\h` means hexadecimal digit.. see updated demo

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html --> More Shorthand Character Classes --> last line refers to `"Ruby 1.9 and later have their own version of \h. It matches a single hexadecimal digit just like [0-9a-fA-F]"`.. just for your reference..

Comment: Looks to me like you are right! @theTinMan has unjustly punished you.

Comment: Duly noted. I'd be careful using special characters like `\h` in a mixed-language environment, or one that is supporting old versions of Ruby though. We use YAML to contain patterns shared among various languages, and something like this would open up a very hard to track bug.